# How to warm start SNOPT in drake

Tags: drake

Hi I was wondering how to warm start the snopt solver in pydrake?

In the documentation for SNOPT it says to use start =2. However I'm not sure how to feed that in properly and also send information from the previous solve into snopt

Answer (score 1):

We haven't supported all the warm-start features in Drake yet. In Drake, you can give it an initial guess

```py
result = Solve(prog, initial_guess)
```

There are other API's to set the initial guess. You can refer to our [tutorial](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/tutorials/mathematical_program.ipynb) in the section "Using an initial guess". You can use the previous solution as the initial guess for the current solve.

We currently don't support warm-starting with dual variable or basis vectors yet.