# Improve the speed of SNOPT solver for MPC trajectory optimization

Tags: python, optimization, drake

I am using pydrake SNOPT to solve a trajectory optimization problem for multi-step walking with linear inverted pendulum model.
The 2-step trajectory takes 0.6s to solve. A speed-up is needed for real-time MPC.

I have tried several ways to improve the speed.

1. Relaxing the tolerance didn't seems to help.

```
self.mp.SetSolverOption(SnoptSolver().solver_id(), "Major feasibility tolerance", 1e-4)
self.mp.SetSolverOption(SnoptSolver().solver_id(), "Minor feasibility tolerance", 1e-4)
```

2. The solve() took 0.2s. Inspecting the snopt.out, I found 600 iterations (major and minor) are completed and 300 QP minor iterations are completed before the first major iteration. Is that an indication that a warm start can help cut down the time by half? Does Drake support warm start for SNOPT? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68736867/how-to-warm-start-snopt-in-drake) says no.
3. One particular constraint is evaluated 500 times and takes 60% of the total solving time. It is a nonlinear Python function. Can I improve it by implementing in Cython or pure C? Are there any resources that show how to do this and how much improvement the Py2C might provide?

Please let me know if there's anything that I might have overlooked. Especially in the snopt.out file.

```
 SNMEMA EXIT 100 -- finished successfully
 SNMEMA INFO 104 -- memory requirements estimated
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question!

For the warm-start, currently we can warm start the primal variable, by passing an initial guess. Here is a pseudo-code

```py
prog.SetInitialGuess(vars, vals)
result = mp.Solve(prog)
```

The first few major iterations in SNOPT usually takes a lot of time.

> Can I improve it by implementing in Cython or pure C?

Yes, I strongly suggest to write your constraint in C++ and then call it from the python binding (Sorry I am not familiar with Cython approach). If your constraint evaluation is in python code, then SNOPT will first call the C++ callback, which then calls the python function. This indirect call across languages can be slow. My colleagues might know a better approach rather than writing a C++ constraint and create the python binding.